# Counting number of quadrilaterals that can be made with a set of points on a circle

Tags: algorithm, geometry, graph-algorithm

Let x^2 + y^2 = r^2 be a circle with r a real.

First I get all integer points that are on the circle (e.g. (1, 2), (-1, 2), (1, -2), (-1, -2), (2, 1), (-2, 1), (2, -1), (-2, -1) for r=sqrt{5})

How can I get the number of quadrilaterals that are possible on with theses points ?

The only way I know is to brute force and test all possible 4-cycles and remove ones with crossing edges but it become too much large for big r. Even for r=sqrt(5) it take about 10 seconds with python.

Comment: What answer did you get after 10 seconds?

Comment: @user3386109 38 quadrilaterals with a space of 210 candidates.

Comment: Any 4 (distinct) points on a circle can be connected to form a quadrilateral right (choose the 4 points in clockwise order for example)? So Isn't the answer just n choose 4 = n*(n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3)/24? Wait -- r needs to be the the largest number in a pythagorean triple (a, b, r) ... (+/-a , +/-b) will given you four points ... hmmm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change approach, start from a simple problem:

Given a set of poins that lie on a circle:

- How many quadrilaterals can you have if the size is 3?

  - Easy: 0
- How many quadrilaterals can you have if the size is 4?

  - Since the points lie on the same circle you will never have 3 points lying on the same straight line. So the answer is 1

now it becomes a bit harder

- How many quadrilaterals can you have if the size is 5?

  - For 4 points we have just one quadrilateral: (p1, p2, p3, p4). Now I can replace each one of them with p5. The total is 5.
- How many quadrilaterals can you have if the size is n?

  - You can have as many quadrilaterals as the number of possible *combinations without repetitions* of a set of n items in subsets of size 4, which is n!/(4!*(n-4)!)

you don't need to know what coordinates have the points, but just how many are them.
Remember: Given 3 points which don't lie on the same straight line you can have only one circle. How ever you get three points from a circle they will never lie one the same straight line. This means that how ever you get 4 points from a circle you can use them to build a quadrilateral

Answer (score 0):

Note that any 4 points on a circle form a quadrilateral (choose them in cw order for example). You just need to find all integral values that are
pythogorean triples where m^n + n^2 = r^2

```
T = 0
for m = 1 ... r
    for n = 1 ... r
        if m*m + n*n = r*r
            T++
N = 4*T  // (+/-m, +/-n) points on circle
result = N > 0 ? (N choose 4) : 0   // all quads
```

You can get rid of the inner loop above for efficiency sake (n^2 = floor(r^2 - m^2))